# How to setup remote notifications without certificate? (RN)

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, iphone-developer-program

I want to test some remote notification services in React Native. But run into some problem. In iOS I need to enable the Push Notifications BUT for that I need a Developer Plan. For testing and playing around of course I do not want to buy an iPhone Developer Program.

Is there a way to test remote push notifications without the need of buying iPhone Developer Program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a paid Apple Developer Program membership is required to use push notifications.

Comment: That quite sad :(.
Well, thanks for clarify it for me, :)